# How to create a complex nested select view?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, subquery

For example this is a restaurant's database, Type 1 means the In-Restaurant, Type 2 means the Orders, Type 3 means the Out-Restaurant.

I want to create a view to view each table's total amount. Total amount means the amount between (Type 1)In-Restaurant time and (Type 3)Out-Restaurant time. Is there any way to create?

Existing Table:

```
Table_No|Type   |Amount     |Time
1       |1      |NULL       |2015-9-17 01:40
1       |2      |5.0        |2015-9-17 01:42
2       |1      |NULL       |2015-9-17 01:43
2       |2      |4.0        |2015-9-17 01:48
1       |2      |5.5        |2015-9-17 01:51
1       |2      |4.0        |2015-9-17 01:52
1       |3      |NULL       |2015-9-17 01:53
2       |2      |3.0        |2015-9-17 01:58
2       |3      |NULL       |2015-9-17 02:00
1       |1      |NULL       |2015-9-17 02:02
1       |2      |4.5        |2015-9-17 02:05
1       |3      |NULL       |2015-9-17 02:10
```

Expected Result:

```
Table_No|Count  |Total_Amount   |Time
1       |3      |14.5           |2015-9-17 01:40
2       |2      |7.0            |2015-9-17 01:43
1       |1      |4.5            |2015-9-17 02:02
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the semantic of you table and view. Do you mean, that when a guest arrives, an entry with type=1 (and amount NULL), when a guest orders an entry with type=2 and corresponding amount, and finally when a guest leaves an entry with type=3 (and amount NULL) is created? And you want to compute what? The time a customer stay in a restaurant? Or the overall money spend for each table? What should `Count` be in your view? What is `Time` in your view?

Comment: Yes, create the record when a guest arrives, orders or leaves .In the view, `count` means no. of items they ordered, `total_amount` means the overall money spend, `time` means the guest arrives time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex query, so I am not going to post a whole query. What you need to do, is to identify each guest that arrived, which is the unique combination of `Table_No, Type=1, Time`. So you need a sub query like this.

```
SELECT Table_No, Time
FROM restaurant_table
WHERE Type = 1
```

For each guest, you need to get the corresponding orders rows in your table. That is, one or multiple type=2 rows. If course, for a single table, there are many "type-2", that belong to other customers. Thus, for each arriving customer, you also need the arrival time of the next customer for the same table. You can figure this one out, by comparing each arriving customer, with all other arriving customers of the same table and pick `min(Time)` for all `Time_othter_customer > Time_current_costomer`. Let's call the view from above `Arrival`

```
SELECT My.Table_No AS Table_No,
       My.Time AS Arrival_Time,
       min(Other.Time) AS Arrival_Next_Customer
FROM Arrival AS My, Arrival AS Other
WHERE My.Table_No = Other.Table_No
      AND Other.Time > My.Time
GROUP BY My.Table_No, My.Time
```

(Pay attention, that for the last customer of each table, there will be no result produced here, because there is no other custom for the same table that arrived later.)

Thus you also need to identify each last customer for each table separately.

```
SELECT Table_No, max(Time) AS Arrival_Time
FROM Arrival
GROUP BY Table_No
```

(Pay attention, that both queries do not have any overlapping result.)

Now you can select the "type-2" entries for each arriving customer. Let's call the view above `ArrivalNext` and `ArrivalLast`

```
SELECT Arrival.Table_No,
       Arrival.Time,
       restaurant_table.Type
       restaurant_table.Amount
FROM ArrivalNext, ArrivalLast, restaurant_table
WHERE (ArrivalNext.Table_No = restaurant_table.Table_No
      AND restaurant_table.Time BETWEEN ArrivalNext.Arrival_Time AND ArrivalNext.Arrival_Next_Customer)
      OR
      (ArrivalLast.Table_No = restaurant_table.Table_No
      AND restaurant_table.Time > ArrivalLast.Arrival_Time)
      AND restaurant_table.Type = 2
```

The join predicate it tricky. If there is a row in `ArrivalNext` the time of the orders must be in between the arrival time of the customer and the arrival time of the next customer (of the same table), because there might be different orders of other customers, too. For this case, we know that there will be no entry in `ArrivalLast`. On the other hand, if the customer was the last one for a table, there is not entry in `ArrivalNext` but in `ArrivalLast` and thus the order times must just be larger than the arrival time, because all orders with a larger timestamp as the arrival time of the last customer belong to the last customer.

Now you can count the "type-2" entries and sum your order amount. Let's call the view above `Customers`:

```
SELECT Table_No
       count(*) AS Count
       sum(Amount) AS Total_Amount
       Time
FROM Customers
WHERE Type = 2
GROUP BY Table_No, Time
```

Of course, you need to put it all together now... (I hope I got it right; at least it should help to derive the correct solution.)

Comment: Thanks, I've created that view successfully! Very useful answer.